# Switching in UITabBarController

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, tabbar

I m working on UITabBarController in iPhone SDK , What I need is, When I click a certain tab It should always be on its Root.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
{
        UINavigationController *navController = [tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:_tabBarController.selectedIndex];
        [navController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
}
```